# Python getchildren() not working for valid XML tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

If I run the following python on an XML file (see bottom of Q):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:\\temp\\test2.xml')
print(tree.getchildren())
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getchildren'

I uploaded the XML to an online validator and it said the XML was fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tree itself has no `getchildren()` method.

```
print(tree.getroot().getchildren())
```

Note that `getchildren()` is deprecated.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects)

Answer (score 5):

`getchildren()` is deprecated.

So use `list(elem)`, in your case use `list(tree.getroot())`

Comment: Relevant for more information about the deprecation: https://bugs.python.org/issue29209. `getchildren` has been deprecated in Python 2.7 and 3.2 and is removed  in Python 3.9.