# In PyQt5, how do you save and restore all items of a QTreeWidget with a random hierarchy?

Tags: user-interface, dynamic, pyqt5, qtreewidget

**Problem**

I have created a UI that will ping on a network that reaches to various different locations. This UI is intended to test 5 different locations with various numbers of machines so the hierarchical view will be different for each location. I would like to save the QTreeWidget when the UI is closed so all changes to have to be reentered on the default template. I have looked online for solutions that people have used but haven't found one that works for my UI. I'm new to using PyQt5 and unsure if there is any function or simple way to save a QTreeWidget. I have attached my code below (I removed code for a few functions that aren't important to the code to fit the question length requirement). I would appreciate any solutions or knowledge anyone has for this.

**EDIT:**

I tried following this example: [Save Treeview Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420012/how-to-save-pyside-tree-view-model-structure)

I am assuming saving as an XML is the best way to format the file. I tried modifying the code in the example but when I parse the XML in importTree, I get the error "root has no attribute get children". It seems that parsing the xml is not being done properly but I don't know what is wrong with the function. I have attached the edited code below. Does anybody know what is wrong with the function or have a better solution?

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, xml):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.header().hide()
        self.importTree(xml)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Export', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.exportTree)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def importTree(self, xml):
        def build(item, root):
            for element in root.getchildren():
                child = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(
                    item, [element.attrib['text']])
                child.setFlags(
                    child.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
                build(child, element)
            item.setExpanded(True)
        root = etree.fromstringlist(xml)
        build(self.tree.invisibleRootItem(), root)

    def exportTree(self):
        def build(item, root):
            for row in range(item.childCount()):
                child = item.child(row)
                element = etree.SubElement(
                    root, 'node', text=child.text(0))
                build(child, element)
        root = etree.Element('root')
        build(self.tree.invisibleRootItem(), root)
        from xml.dom import minidom
        print(minidom.parseString(etree.tostring(root)).toprettyxml())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    xml = """\
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <node text="PPG">
        <node text="Machine 1">
            <node text="Machine Router"/>
            <node text="Machine Radio"/>
        </node>
        <node text="Access Point"/>
    </node>
    <node text="Edwards">
        <node text="Machine 1">
            <node text="Machine Router"/>
            <node text="Machine Radio"/>
        </node>
        <node text="Access Point 1"/>
    </node>
    <node text="Tinaja">
        <node text="Machine 1">
            <node text="Machine Router"/>
            <node text="Machine Radio"/>
        </node>
        <node text="Access Point 1"/>
    </node>
    <node text="Tuscon">
        <node text="Machine 1">
            <node text="Machine Router"/>
            <node text="Machine Radio"/>
        </node>
        <node text="Access Point 1"/>
    </node>
    <node text="Clayton">
        <node text="Machine 1">
            <node text="Machine Router"/>
            <node text="Machine Radio"/>
        </node>
        <node text="Access Point 1"/>
    </node>
</root>"""
    window = Window(xml)
    window.setGeometry(800, 300, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please note that you're ***not*** supposed to edit pyuic generated files. Read more about the proper way to use UI files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @musicamante Sorry for editing the generated file. This is my first time using pyuic and Designer so I am not completely sure of all the formatting and standards. I am only trying to create a UI for internal use and I used python because I just need the interface to regularly ping an entered ip address. I tried editing my code based on an example from a similar question. However, I am still having some problems. I would appreciate if you have any advice/solutions.

Comment: If you do a simple search with "xml etree root has no attribute get children" you'll find out a lot of related results: [`getchildren()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren) is deprecated since python 3.2 and removed since 3.9. Use `for element in list(root):`. Duplicate of [Python getchildren() not working for valid XML tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49457644).

Comment: Note: there's nothing wrong in using pyuic files. The point is, as said, that you should *not* modify those files, but follow what's explained in the link above.